Reduction of a power series modulo the characteristic polynomial
Define the power series: $$f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_mx^m$$
And the characteristic polynomial: $$x^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx^k$$ With extra coefficient $$c_{-1},c_{-2},\dots=0$$
The goal is reduce the power series $f(x)$ into a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n-1$ by substituting in repeatly the characteristic polynomial to elmininate the $x^n,x^{n+1},\dots$ terms, to do that, then one would need to represent $x^n,x^{n+1},x^{n+2},\dots$ as polynomials in $x$ of degree $n-1$. Then substitute them into the original power series.
$$x^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-1}x^k+c_{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx^k$$
$$x^{n+2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-2}x^k+(c_{n-1}+c_{n-2})\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-1}x^k+c_{n-1}^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx^k$$
$$x^{n+3}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-3}x^k+(c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}+c_{n-3})\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-2}x^k+(c_{n-1}^2+c_{n-1}c_{n-2}+c_{n-2}^2)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-1}x^k+c_{n-1}^3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx^k$$
$$x^{n+4}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-4}x^k+(c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}+c_{n-3}+c_{n-4})\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-3}x^k+(c_{n-1}^2+c_{n-2}^2+c_{n-3}^2+c_{n-1}c_{n-2}+c_{n-1}c_{n-3}+c_{n-2}c_{n-3})\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k-2}x^k+(c_{n-1}^3+c_{n-1}^2c_{n-2}+c_{n-1}c_{n-2}^2+c_{n-2}^3)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-1}x^k+c_{n-1}^4\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx^k$$
$$\dots$$
For the $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k$ term then it's coefficient is a multivariable polynomial in $c_{n-1},c_{n-2},\dots,c_{n-1-t}$ in which the polynomial has all terms with only degree $m-t$ and coefficient $1$. Thus the general formula for $x^{n+m}$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ is:
$$x^{n+m}=\sum_{t=0}^m\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k$$
Now we will prove the formula above is true of all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Since we have proved it for some $m=m_0$. We will prove it by induction:
$$x^{n+m+1}=\sum_{t=0}^m\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^{k+1}$$
$$x^{n+m+1}=\sum_{t=0}^m\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(c_{k-t-1}+c_{n-t-1}c_{k-t})x^k$$
$$x^{n+m+1}=\sum_{t=0}^m\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-t-1}x^k+\sum_{t=0}^m\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{n-t-1}c_{k-t}x^k$$
$$x^{n+m+1}=\sum_{t=1}^{m+1}\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_t=m-t+1}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-t}^{k_t}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k+\sum_{t=0}^m\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}+1}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k$$
$$x^{n+m+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-m-1}x^k+\sum_{t=1}^{m}\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_t=m-t+1}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-t}^{k_t}+\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}+1}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k+k_1^m\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx^k$$
For the first sum in the big parenthesis, there is no $c_{n-1-t}$, and in the second sum, there is no term which has no $c_{n-1-t}$, if we add them together, we can rewrite it like this:
$$x^{n+m+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-m-1}x^k+\sum_{t=1}^{m}\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m+1-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k+k_1^m\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx^k$$
$$x^{n+m+1}=\sum_{t=0}^{m+1}\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m+1-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k$$
Thus, the formula holds true for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$.
It's necessary to remove the extra coefficient. Which means $k-t\ge0$ or $t\le k\le n-1$. The formula becomes:
$$x^{n+m}=\sum_{t=0}^{min(m,n-1)}\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=t}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k$$
The $min(m,n-1)$ is there instead of $m$ is because if $m\gt n-1$ and $t\gt n-1$, the term vanishes.
The power series becomes:
$$f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}a_mx^m+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_{m+n}\sum_{t=0}^{min(m,n-1)}\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=t}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k$$
One could use analytic continuation in case the sum diverges, thus completed the goal in reducing the power series
Question: What is the condition for $a_n$ so that $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_{m+n}\sum_{t=0}^{min(m,n-1)}\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_{t+1}=m-t}c_{n-1}^{k_1}c_{n-2}^{k_2}\dots c_{n-1-t}^{k_{t+1}}\right)\sum_{k=t}^{n-1}c_{k-t}x^k$ exist an analytic continuation?

Incomprehensible. No line seems to be related to a previous line, there must be a lot of exposition missing. And what does "reducing a power series into a polynomial" mean? A power series is a power series, it isn't a polynomial. And what is the characteristic polynomial of a power series?

What is your aim ? Initial question ? Initial exercise or issue ?

@EDX question. I edit it a little, hope you can review

The whole thing depends on the characteristic polynomial of a power series – you can't even start the procedure without that. Now, I asked you yesterday, what you meant by that phrase, and you refuse to answer. What is "the characteristic polynomial of a power series"? (Also, several of your formulas are way too long, they run into the "Hot Network Questions" and are unreadable.)

@GerryMyerson my English is not that good so I couldn't explain it to you what it means, but you can edit the question's title if you like:)

If you can't tell us what "characteristic polynomial of a power series" means, then how do you expect anyone to answer your question? Can you give an example or two or three of a power series with its corresponding characteristic polynomial? Maybe we could use that to figure out what you mean. Do you have a friend who knows math and has the English skills to explain to us what the characteristic polynomial of a power series is? Can you point to a page in a book that uses that phrase?

@GerryMyerson sorry I can't but my goal is to reduce a power series in x into a polynomial of degree n-1 with x satisfy the equation x^n=polynomial degree n-1 in x

And what makes you think it's possible to do that? Do you have even one example of a power series reduced into a polynomial?

I'm going to make believe I understand the question, and try to show why there may be no way to do what OP tries to do.
Consider the power series
$$
f(x)=\sum_0^{\infty}F_nx^n=x+x^2+2x^3+3x^4+5x^5+8x^6+\dotsb
$$
where the $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers: $0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,\dotsc$.
Now, I can think of two possible interpretations of "characteristic polynomial of the series $\sum_0^{\infty}c_nx^n$," which amount to the same thing. First, if the series is a rational function $P(x)/Q(x)$ (which is the exception for power series, not the rule), reduced to lowest terms, then one could, I suppose, call $Q(x)$ the characteristic polynomial of the series. In our example, we have
$$
f(x)={x\over1-x-x^2}
$$
so the characteristic polynomial would be $1-x-x^2$.
Alternatively (but equivalently), if the $c_n$ satisfy a constant-coefficient linear recurrence relation,
$$
c_{n+1}=u_1c_n+u_2c_{n-1}+\dotsb+u_kc_{n+1-k}
$$
(which, again, is the exception, not the rule), then we could call $x^k=u_1x^{k-1}+u_2x^{k-2}+\dotsb+u_k$ the characteristic equation of the power series. In our example, we have $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$, so the characteristic equation would be $x^2=x+1$. So, $x$ is a zero of $x^2-x-1$, which is just the reciprocal polynomial of $1-x-x^2$ that we got from the other interpretation.
Now let's see what happens when we try to reduce the power series to a polynomial. From $x^2=x+1$, we get
$x^3=x^2+x=(x+1)+x=2x+1$,
$x^4=2x^2+x=2(x+1)+x=3x+2$,
$x^5=3x^2+2x=3(x+1)+2x=5x+3$,
and, in general, $x^n=F_nx+F_{n-1}$.
Plugging all this into the power series, we get
$$
f(x)=x+(x+1)+2(2x+1)+3(3x+2)+5(5x+3)+\dotsb
$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad=(1+1+4+9+25+\dotsb)x+(1+2+6+15+\dotsb)=\infty x+\infty
$$
which is pretty useless. A power series isn't a polynomial, and you can't "reduce it" into one, no matter how hard you try.

If analytic continuation are allowed, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n^2=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F_nF_{n-1}=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)$ reduces to $-\frac{1}{2}$, while $\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{x}{1-x-(x+1)}=-\frac{1}{2}$
